# How to include sqlite db file into jar in netbeans?

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans, jar

I use sqlite in my java application. When I run it from Netbeans, it works well. The sqlite db file is located in the root project directory (same level as build.xml).
This is the code to access the database file:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:database.db");
```

However, when I build the project, and run the jar file outside netbeans, I always get this error: `no such table: table_name`

My question: where is the correct location to put the "sqlite db" file? Is it possible to package it inside the JAR file?

I have tried to package my application into a single JAR file (similar to Eclipse's FatJar), but I still get that error. In this case I modify the build.xml as explained in this blog:
[Netbeans single JAR](http://arnoraps.tweakblogs.net/blog/4300/netbeans-single-jar.html)

I also tried to create a database folder in the src directory and then put the db file inside the folder (src/database/database.db) and access it using

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:src/database/database.db");
```

I can run it inside netbeans. But when I run it outside, I got this error:

```
path to 'src/database/database.db':C:\Windows\system32\src' does not exist
```

I know there are similar questions to this in stackoverflow, but most of them don't have a concrete solution. Let me know if someone has found a better one.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved!

I made a mistake in the way I execute the JAR file. Previously I run the JAR file by right click on it and open it with Java SE binary. I need to do this because in my PC the default program to open JAR file was set to another software.
It turned out that I have to set the default program to Java SE Binary and the double click the JAR file in order to run my application. Using this way I can run and access the sqlite db file without a problem.

I hope this can help others who may get the same problem as I had.

Answer (score 0):

probably you need to point your app to include your app base directory in the classpath.
the command to run your app should be something like:

```
java -cp . YourAppMainClass
```

the "-cp . " is the command option that tells java to include current directory in the classpath.